# Julia Pkg.clone()ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Stats [072d6d2a]:

Tags: julia

I have Julia, Juno, and Atom installed in my computer. It works well. I was trying to use Pkg.clone() based on this link:https://github.com/uoa-ems-research/JEMSS.jl 
I got the error message like the following:

```
julia> Pkg.clone("https://github.com/samridler/JEMSS.jl.git")
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/samridler/JEMSS.jl.git`
[ Info: Assigning UUID 24979329-2a3d-50cf-82e3-05af2f1830ac to JEMSS
[ Info: Path `/Users/jack/.julia/dev/JEMSS` exists and looks like the correct package, using existing path instead of cloning
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Stats [072d6d2a]:
 Stats [072d6d2a] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.0.1, 0.1.0] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions 0.0.0-* by JEMSS [24979329], leaving only versions [0.0.1, 0.1.0]
 │ └─JEMSS [24979329] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 0.0.0 or uninstalled
 │   └─JEMSS [24979329] is fixed to version 0.0.0
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
Stacktrace:
 [1] #propagate_constraints!#61(::Bool, ::Function, ::Pkg.GraphType.Graph, ::Set{Int64}) at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/GraphType.jl:1005
 [2] propagate_constraints! at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/GraphType.jl:946 [inlined]
 [3] #simplify_graph!#121(::Bool, ::Function, ::Pkg.GraphType.Graph, ::Set{Int64}) at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/GraphType.jl:1460
 [4] simplify_graph! at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/GraphType.jl:1460 [inlined]
 [5] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:317 [inlined]
 [6] resolve_versions!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}, ::Nothing) at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:353
 [7] resolve_versions! at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:316 [inlined]
 [8] #add_or_develop#62(::Array{Base.UUID,1}, ::Symbol, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1201
 [9] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [10] #add_or_develop#13(::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:64
 [11] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [12] #develop#19 at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:70 [inlined]
 [13] develop at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:70 [inlined]
 [14] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:308 [inlined]
 [15] clone(::String, ::String) at /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:468 (repeats 2 times)
 [16] top-level scope at none:0
```

So, it looks like I need to clear/delete the file located at.  ./Users/jack/.julia/dev/JEMSS   and try this again, right? Maybe because I cloned this file more than once I guess? Is there a command I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Stats package is not compatible with your julia versions, which looks like it is 0.7 or 1.0 based on the messages. Just `rm` the package. For now you'll have to load the JuliaStats packages manually.

Comment: Thank you. I kind of figure it out and was ready to answer it. ;) Yes. My Julia installed is of version 1.0. I do not have Stats package installed though. When I was trying to install the Stats package, I got the similar error though.

Comment: julia> Pkg.add("Stats")
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Stats [072d6d2a]:
 Stats [072d6d2a] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.0.1, 0.1.0] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [0.0.1, 0.1.0]
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left

Comment: No but the JEMSS package tries to install it - and I think the JEMSS package is also only 0.6, so you can't install it. Try `]rm JEMSS` then `]resolve`. The package looks like it's being actively worked upon so you could try to ask the developers in an issue what the status is. Generally, though, you should not expect good results when installing a package where ALL of the badges on github show it as "failing"

Comment: what is the meaning that "... ALL of the badges on GitHub show it is "failing" ..." Could you Kindly let me know?

Comment: ] will help me open the package Pkg mode, right? I tried ] rm JEMSS, it does not work,(v1.0) pkg> rm JEMSS
┌ Warning: `JEMSS` not in project, ignoring
└ @ Pkg.Operations /Users/osx/buildbot/slave/package_osx64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1156
[ Info: No changes