# Julia pkg> add MatpowerCases: ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package MatpowerCases [c59b8745]:

Tags: dependencies, julia, matpower

I am new to Julia, and I'm trying to add the MatpowerCases package to do some power flow computations. However, when I tried `]add MatpowerCases` this is what I get:

```
(v1.1) pkg> add MatpowerCases
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package MatpowerCases [c59b8745]:
 MatpowerCases [c59b8745] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.0.1, 0.1.0, 0.2.0-0.2.1, 0.3.0-0.3.2, 0.4.0, 0.5.0] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [0.0.1, 0.1.0, 0.2.0-0.2.1, 0.3.0-0.3.2, 0.4.0, 0.5.0]
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
```

Does this mean I need to use install Julia v0.5.0 or earlier to use this package? I found this similar question: [Julia Pkg.clone()ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Stats [072d6d2a]:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598548/julia-pkg-cloneerror-unsatisfiable-requirements-detected-for-package-stats-0), and tried `rm MatpowerCases` but got this (which is kind of obvious wouldn't work):

```
(v1.1) pkg> rm MatpowerCases
┌ Warning: `MatpowerCases` not in project, ignoring
└ @ Pkg.Operations C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.0\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:1192
[ Info: No changes
```

The package I'm trying to add can be found here: https://github.com/kersulis/MatpowerCases.jl

How do I proceed? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like that package is rather old and not maintained. Maybe you can take a look at PowerModels.jl : https://lanl-ansi.github.io/PowerModels.jl/stable/

Comment: @clbieganek Thank you!